# How to bind a string from singleton in xaml (WinRT / C#)

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-runtime

i've created a Singleton which contains a string.
Now i want to bind this string to a TextBlock an Xaml.

```
<TextBlock Visibility="Visible" Text="{Binding singleton.Instance.newsString, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

When i run the WinRT App, the TextBlock-Text-String is empty.

**EDIT 1:**

Now it runs. But when i change the string in the singleton the TextBlock does not update.

Here is the c# code from my singleton

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public sealed class singleton : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static readonly singleton instance = new singleton();
        public static singleton Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return instance;
            }
        }

        private singleton() { }

        private string _newsString;
        public string newsString
        {
            get
            {
                if (_newsString == null)
                    _newsString = "";
                return _newsString;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_newsString != value)
                {
                    _newsString = value;
                    this.RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("newsString");
                }
            }
        }

        private void RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

In my code behind the xaml i do this

```
        singleton.Instance.newsString = "Breaking news before init";
        this.Resources.Add("newsStringResource", singleton.Instance.newsString);
        this.InitializeComponent();
        singleton.Instance.newsString = "Breaking news AFTER init";
```

and in the xaml i bind the Resource with

```
        <TextBlock Visibility="Visible" Text="{StaticResource newsStringResource}" />
```

With this code the TextBlock shows "Breaking news before init".
Whats wrong now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your singleton to app resources using code behind before the `TextBlock` is constructed and reference the singleton by key.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! But now another problem appeared. Look at "Edit1"

Comment: You're not binding a resource, you basically set a resource. You need to set the instance of your singleton as a resource and then do `Text="{Binding DownloadMgrString, Source={StaticResource MySingletonResourceKey}"`